# Communication between Python and VBA

Tags: python, vba, communication

I try to design a programm in VBA (used within a simulation software) which is able to call Python for some calculations and receive the result to proceed. The VBA-Python call will happen many times.

My first idea is based on a text file communication, e.g. something like this:

```
in VBA:
do something

write text file 'calc_todo.txt' in specific directory

while not exists 'calc_finished.txt':
    wait 1 second

read 'calc_finished.txt'

delete'calc_finished.txt'

delete'calc_todo.txt'

do something

write text file 'calc_todo.txt' in specific directory

... repeat



in Python:
do something

while not exists 'calc_todo.txt':
    wait 1 second

read 'calc_todo.txt'

do calculations based on 'calc_todo.txt'

write 'calc_finished.txt'

delete'calc_todo.txt'

do something

while not exists 'calc_todo.txt':
    wait 1 second

... repeat
```

I have done something similar in past and unfortunately there are a lot of things I do not like:

- fixed waiting time of e.g. 1 second might slow down performance
- if something breaks VBA and/or Python will get stuck in a while loop or run in an error
- to fix the second issue, error handling with initialisation can be implemented but last time it was a mess

What would be a more professional way on how to handle such communication?

Comment: A file can exist (by name) before all its contents have been written and the file is available and populated as expected. It's size however can be a guide.

Comment: If you want to ensure that a file is ready for processing, create the first first with a temporary name and rename it only after finish writing.

Comment: I have used this approach successfully, creating a shell and running a script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356710/call-python-script-from-vba-with-wsh